# How to push an object with two key/value pairs into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to take this array as an argument

`var movies = ['matrix','the dark knight','a beautiful mind','american pie']`

for a function that loops through that array and pushes the titles as object into a new array adding an id (from the loop index) along the way.

The new arr should look like this

`['{title:matrix, id:0}','{title:the dark knight, id:1}','{title:a beautiful mind, id:2}','{title:american pie, id:3}']`

This is the function and I know I have a syntax error. But where?

```
function addToList(arr) {
    var movieList = []

    for (var x of arr) {
        movieList{["titel"]=arr, ["id"]=x}
    }
    return movieList
}
```

Comment: Did you try to print the output and see what's wrong? What do you expect to happen when you're using the syntax: `movieList{..}` ?

Comment: The same way ANY object is added to an array.. separate the two concepts to make it “clear”. 1) *create object(s), using an intermediate expression or variable*; 2) add object(s) to the target array. Once this separation is well understood, the problem can be diced in several different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using `array.map`

```
 function addToList(arr) {
        var movieList = []

        for (var i in arr) {
            movieList[i]={title:arr[i], id:i}
        }
        return movieList
    }
```

OR

```
function addToList(arr) {
    var movieList = []

    for (var i in arr) {
        movieList.push({title:arr[i], id:i});
    }
    return movieList
}
```

Comment: THX. Just to be sure: 

in the first approach I set the i-th element of the movieList array to an object {} that contains titel as a key and the i-th arr as value and id as a key with i as value. 

right?

Comment: `i` is just a number... not depending from array.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use `.map()` to get the desired output:

```js
const data = ['matrix','the dark knight','a beautiful mind','american pie']

const result = data.map((m, i) => ({title: m, id: i}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Not there yet ... map is in a future chapter

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addToList(arr) {
    var movieList = []

    for (var x of arr) {
        movieList.push({titel: arr, id: x});
    }
    return movieList
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) statement iterates over values of the object, not the indices (properties).

You can use [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement to iterate over indices (properties) of the object.

```js
var movies = ['matrix','the dark knight','a beautiful mind','american pie'];

function addToList(arr) {
    var movieList = [];

    for (var i in arr) {
        movieList[i] = {"title": arr[i], "id": i};
    }

    return movieList;
}

console.log(addToList(movies));
```